# Scrolling mouse sets windows sound volume

Tags: windows-7, audio, mouse-wheel

Suddenly, when I use the scroll wheel of my mouse, it changes the windows sound volume level.

I have a HP DV6-2030SD laptop with Windows 7 64 bit and a Zolid p50622 mouse. When I use the scroll function of the mouse pad of the laptop, it does not adjust the sound level.

I don't have any special mouse drivers installed, just the standard windows drivers. When I scroll, I see the HP sound level screen:

[image]

It doesn't do it always, but when it does, it prevents the current window to scroll, which is really annoying. Rebooting doesn't help. I've tried to put the USB dongle in a different port, but this doesn't help either.

Any advise on how I can fix this?

**Edit:**

- I noticed that the navigation buttons (previous and next) also don't work when it happens.
- Removing the windows device from the device manager didn't help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem. It has to do with the DPI switch of the mouse. It has been pushed into the casing of the mouse which made it act like that. After freeing the button (and reinserting the batteries) it worked again.

Comment: just had the same problem, it's indeed caused by pressing the DPI button for a few seconds, that's what you need to do to switch it back. one of the hidden windows futures lol

Answer (score 0):

When I click the loudspeaker icon in the lower right corner (near the time) and then use the scroll-wheel, the volume is set while turning the wheel.

So my question is: can it be that you (accidentally) activated the volume icon, maybe by pressing a special button or key on the notebook, before the volume bar is shown instead of scrolling the window?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with this. It happens even if I reboot the computer. When I click the mouse-wheel, it switches sound on and off.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried installing the correct drivers for your Mouse? Maybe that could help.

Comment: I've never needed to. I have been using this mouse for months. It just happened in an instance. But it is something I could try.

Comment: It looks like there are no real drivers available for this mouse.